# Instead of using openfire ofUser, i want to use my user table

Tags: php, android, mysql, chat, openfire

I have successfully merged my database with the openfire database, now i have two tables in my database, "myUser" which is my table of all the app user and the other one is "ofUser" which is the table used by the openfire. Now what i want is, i dont want to use my "myUser" table, i want to use "ofUser" so that all the app users which are created, will be listed directly in "ofuser"table.

I tried researching and checked the official document of the openfire, but nothing helped. If i can't do that, what is the other possible way to achieve my requirements.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple. I used this table in my app to create user account.just insert data into 'ofuser' table except the encryptedPassword field . just use tha plainPassword field to log in.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what your problem is.  Openfire will use the ofUser table by default if you are using DB based authentication.  There isn't anything for you to do.  It isn't going to use your myUser table unless you have created a custom authentication component.

Comment: Thank You robin for your reply.  Okay, so i need to create custom authentication component in openfire.xml ????